# Looking for an ebook about typography that used to be part of a package

Tags: packages, typography, books

Sorry for asking, but an iron-curtain seems to have settled in my brain...

I'm looking for a ebook about typography and how to best write/typeset a book.  It used to be part of the documentation for some TeX/LaTeX package (I assume to help typeset books and similar), but was later split into a separate package.  It's available both as a TeX/LaTeX-sourcefile and as a PDF.

The book gives a brief history of and introduction to typography - Gutenberg, lead-types, old-style printing-presses, different measurements used; as well as a descriptions of the various parts of a typical book - foreword, introduction, title-page, copyright-page (what that string of number means), and so on.  I only read the two first chapters, but I got the impression the book would be about how to typeset and section books.

Anyway, since I don't remember the name of the packages (the original and the one with just the book), the webpage (I think it had one), the author nor the title; I'm asking here - does anybody remember this ebook?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are very likely looking for [`memdesign`](http://ctan.org/pkg/memdesign). Quoting the package description:

> “A Few Notes on Book De­sign” pro­vides an in­tro­duc­tion to the
>   busi­ness of book de­sign. It is an ex­tended ver­sion of what used to
>   be the first part of the mem­oir users’ man­ual.

Comment: TeX Live provides it under `texdoc memdesign`

Comment: Yeah, damn it! That part of the `memoir` documentation is actually the reason why I'm still doing everything in `memoir` instead of using the more modular KOMA-Script. Well, that and the butt-ugly defaults of the KOMA-Script classes. That `memoir` introduction really convinced me that those people knew what they were doing.

Comment: Yes, that's the one.  Thanks!  Excellent book.  I've also fount it educational to look at the TeX-source while reading it.

Comment: @BaardKopperud Not directly related to the question, there is a excelent book about typography: **The Elements of Typographic Style**, Robert Bringhurst, Hartley and Marks, Publishers, 2004.